For $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$ with $A+A'=\pi$ and $B=B'$, show $aa'=bb'+cc'$, without using Pythagoras, Stewart, or the Law of Cosines
From the Croatian National Mathematical Competition (2002), 2nd Grade Problem #3:

If two triangles with side lengths $a,b,c$ and $a',b',c'$ and the
corresponding angles $α, β, γ$ and $α', β', γ'$ satisfy $α + α' = π$
and $β = β'$, prove that $aa′ = bb′ +cc′$

It is quite easy to prove that using Stewart's theorem or the law of cosines, but is there any way to avoid directly or indirectly the use of those theorems and the Pythagorean theorem too?
I ask because I would like to prove the Pythagorean theorem from that fact (I know it's silly and that is highly probable that even if an argument exist it was already used to prove that directly)
Proof using Stewart's theorem:
Starting with the black triangle, among all the ones satisfy $α + α' = π $ and $β = β'$ we chose the red one with two vertex in common with the black one. Now the $ b$ side is a cevian so we can apply the Stewart's theorem, remembering that $ a^2 = a'^2= aa′ $, so
$ (c + c')(bb′ + cc′) = aa′c' + aa′c  \rightarrow aa′ = bb′ +cc′$
Now this relation holds even for any triangle similar to the red one, so we demonstrated that it holds in every case.


"It is quite easy to prove that using Stewart's theorem or the law of cosines" ... Please include such proofs, so that others can avoid duplicating the effort. Moreover, someone may be able to readily see how to avoid Stewart and/or LoC in your work without starting from scratch.

Draw the triangles and you will see how to construct a single shape and paly with it.

@Blue just added, thank you!

Why b'=b? a'=a?

@Moti that derives by the particular choice of the red triangle (because the big one is isosceles)

The triangle you drew is not the right description since you added constrains b=b' and a=a'. Draw it with $\beta$ at the top.

Then apply similarity and bisector rules.

@user967210 Yes, it is possible to prove the formula without those theorems. Let's construct a triangle $ABC$ such that $BC = a, CA = b, AB = c$, then there is a point $D$ such that $\angle BAC + \angle BDC = \pi$ and $\angle DCB = \angle ABC$. Therefore the triangle $DCB$ is similar to the triangle with sidelengths $a', b', c'$. $ABDC$ is an isosceles trapezoid (hence cyclic). By Ptolemy's theorem, $AB\cdot CD + AC\cdot BD = AD\cdot BC$. Hence the result follows.

@DuongNgo how do you choose $D$? Can you show the construction?

@user967210 I construct $D$ such that $ABDC$ is an isosceles trapezoid where $AB\parallel CD$.

@Duong this is not a specific construction. A general construction will not be a trapezoid.

I added a solution for the graphic purpose to help you, not as a solution.

@Moti Yes, in general, it is not even convex. But in this problem, it is. I posted my full answer.

You are correct!

I give a proof using Ptolemy's theorem.
Firstly, construct a triangle $ABC$ such that $BC = a, CA = b, AB = c$. Because $\alpha + \alpha' = \pi$ and $\beta = \beta'$, it follows that $\beta = \beta' = \pi - \alpha' - \gamma' = \alpha - \gamma' < \alpha$, which implies $CA < CB$.

Let $D$ be the reflection of $C$ across the perpendicular bisector $d$ of the line segment $AB$. $CA < CB$ so $C, A$ are on the same side of $d$. $DA > DB$ so $D, B$ are on the same side of $d$. $A, B$ are on the opposite sides of $d$. We deduce that $ABDC$ is a convex quadrilateral. Moreover, $AB$ is parallel to $CD$, and the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $AB$ is the axis of symmetry of $ABDC$, so $ABDC$ is an isosceles trapezoid.
$\angle BDC = \angle ACD = \pi - \angle BAC = \pi - \alpha = \alpha'$ and $\angle DCB = \angle ABC = \beta = \beta'$. Therefore $(BC : DB : DC) \sim (a' : b' : c')$. Every isosceles trapezoid is cyclic, so $AD\cdot BC = AB\cdot CD + AC\cdot BD$, according to Ptolemy's theorem. Hence $aa' = bb' + cc'$.

Here are two configurations that you could use to make it as required.

